# Showing JavaScript Alert Message inside UpdatePanel in ASP.Net Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Hi i found this below solution with ScriptManager

```
string message = "alert('Hello!')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
```

the issue is i am using ToolkitScriptManager

How can make the code work with ToolkitScriptManager

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work with ToolScriptManager also(only if you have **PostBack** trigger)

```
 Response.Write(@"<script Language=""javascript"" >alert('"+Your Message here+"')</script>");
```

Code below works with both ToolScriptManager and ScriptManager(For **Async Trigger** also)

```
 String TransferPage;
 TransferPage = "<script>alert('Your Message')</script>";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "temp", TransferPage, false);
```